# jQuery trigger mouseup on dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventtrigger

I want to cancel dragging by jQuery trigger `mouseup`

**HTML:**

`<div ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true"></div>`

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on("mouseup","body",function(){
        exit_dragging();
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function(){
        alert('mouseup');
    });

});

function drag(event){ 
    event.preventDefault();
    $(document).trigger("mouseup"); //alert('mouseup') runs
    //.....      
}
```

when mouse is releasing the `exit_dragging()` runs but I want to run it when `triggering`.

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 3):

A quick google gave me the following

Html:

```
<div id='div' draggable="true">
</div>
```

Script:

```
$("#div").click(function(){
 alert('clicked'); 
});

$("#div").hover(function(){
 $("#div").trigger( "click" );
});
```

This runs click on hover, similarly there might be way to run mouseup on drag.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xq4m6oyy/)

Edit I:

Try this if it works

```
$("#div").mouseup(function(){
 alert('mouseup'); 
});


$('#div').bind('drag',function( event ){
 $("#div").trigger( "mouseup" );
});
```

Comment: sorry, but i ll try to get you a solution

Comment: thanks , solved by `jQuery draggable`, and `start:function(e){ e.preventDefault();....  })`

Comment: Add it as answer .. might be helpful for others

Comment: @A J : Okay as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

```
function drag(event){ 
    event.preventDefault();
    $(document).mouseup();
}
```

See if this works.

Comment: when `mouseup` runs other actions (like `hover`, ...) not working.

Comment: try to fire the mouse up on specific div.